# How get generic parameter in scala

Tags: generics, scala

I would like to be able to perform the following code:

```
abstract class A[T <: AnyRef]{
  def whichClass: Class[_] = classOf[T]
}

case class X()

object B extends A[X]

object Main{
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    B.whichClass //should return classOf[X]
  }
}
```

Clearly, it doesn't work in this form, since `classOf[T]` can be only assignged to class, not type. A got an error:

```
error: class type required but T found
def whichClass: Class[_] = classOf[T]
```

Any idea how solve this problem in another way?

Answer (score 9):

Use [ClassManifest](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/reflect/ClassManifest.html).

```
abstract class A[T <: AnyRef : ClassManifest] {
  def whichClass = classManifest[T].erasure
}

case class X()

object B extends A[X]

object Main{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(B.whichClass) // prints 'class X'
  }
}
```

Comment: @missing, any idea if this approach will change with new reflection in 2.10?